# undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup' in linux

Tags: c, linux, windows

Hi I want to build an application for windows in `C`, I program in linux and compile the code with `gcc` and `mingw-w64`.

I tried a simple program with output and input it works fine on windows.

But, I want to use sockets to connect to a server.

So I searched in google and found this tutorial http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/intro.html#audience

It says that in windows we need to include `winsock` and run some command
So I did:

```
#include <winsock.h>
int main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    printf("Hello! This is a test prgoram.\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsaData) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed.\n");
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile it I get:

> undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

In command line all that I run was:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc try.c -o a.exe
```

So what I should do? 
If I compile in linux I don't need the `winsock` library?
How to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [WSAStartup Manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx) and scroll a bit down, you will find what library it is defined in: `Ws2_32.lib`

This is an "import library", a stub you need to link against for a windows program to use the respective DLLs. MinGW includes all standard windows platform import libraries. So you just need to link it, using `-lws2_32`.

Comment: Hey thanks, it works, but if I will need another library, how to include two?

Comment: just add another `-l` flag with the name of the other library. This is not different from compiling for linux.