# Qt undefined reference when building project with external header

Tags: c++, qt, header, undefined-reference

I'm trying to build a small GUI using Qt Creator which sends HTTP requests when pushing a button. To send those requests I included an external header file ("HTTPRequests.hpp", https://github.com/elnormous/HTTPRequest). The header file is located in my project folder. I included the header file in my .pro like this:

```
HEADERS += \
    HTTPRequest.hpp \
    mainwindow.h
```

and in the .h file like this:

```
#include <HTTPRequest.hpp>
```

When I want to build my application, there are many errors such as:

```
undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
```

or

```
undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'
```

I couldn't find a working solution yet.

Comment: You need to link to `Ws2_32.lib` as the documentation for WSAStartup tells you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup)

Comment: First google result tells me that you are on windows and you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221696/undefined-reference-to-imp-wsastartup-in-linux

Comment: It worked! Didn't know it was that easy... I'm feeling kinda stupid right now... Well, thank you very much!